# Почему Yandex.Cloud.Functions не может импортировать модуль aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram, yandex-cloud

Я написал бота для телеграмма и хочу запустить его на Yandex.Cloud.Functions. Когда я перенес код в Yandex.Cloud.Functions ничего не работает.

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
```

Обратился к "тестированию" и выдает следующую ошибку!

```
{
    "errorMessage": "Unable to import module index: No module named 'aiogram'",
    "errorType": "HandlerImportError",
    "stackTrace": [
        "  File \"/function/runtime/runtime.py\", line 174, in load_handler\n    raise HandlerImportError('Unable to import module {}: {}'.format(file_name, str(e)))\n"
    ]
}
```

Ранее с сервисом не работал, могу чего то не понимать, так что сразу извиняюсь. Как я могу подгрузить aiogram туда, чтобы бот работал? Или как запустить код через другой хостинг, какие они вообще есть? Буду благодарен любой информации!

Comment: Не шарю в яндексКлауд, но с чего вы взяли что там есть айограм?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить зависимости в файл requirements.txt
Создайте этот файл и напишите в нем aiogram.